# How to monitor machine status on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services

how do you guys often monitor the status of your vm on EC2?

I am currently using CloudWatch and it seems that it can only give me CPU/network/io related stuff.

What's your recommendation of server monitoring tool on AWS EC2? What are the pros and cons?

Answer (score 1):

**CloudWatch** is far enough for testing the health of EC2 instance.

If you need something more detailed inside the EC2, you could have a look at [**monit**](http://mmonit.com/monit/).

> Monit is a small Open Source utility for managing and monitoring Unix systems. Monit conducts automatic maintenance and repair and can execute meaningful causal actions in error situations.